Vegetation Change Tracker and GEE: What do the six bands output by the VCT algorithm mean?
What do the six bands output by the VCT algorithm mean, especially the values ​​of the VCT landcover mask. I don't know what they mean.
Vegetation Change Tracker, an automated approach for reconstructing recent forest disturbance history using dense Landsat time series stacks.
The output is a 2D array per pixel containing 6 rows x N years. The output rows contain: input years, VCT landcover mask, magnitude in term of the UD composite, magnitude of distubance in B4, magnitude of distubance in NDVI, magnitude of distubance in dNBR.
